# Parent process unexpectedly killed by child cmd.exe process running java jar - WINDOWS 7 PROBLEM - C++

Tags: java, c++, crash, windows-7

*Info about the project:* I am creating a C++ console application that manages a Minecraft server by listening to port activity. When server port is pinged, it starts the server and then periodically checks if there are established connections on that port. If none, the server is shut down and app goes into listening mode once again.

The problem arises when the server is stopped. Somehow my main console app is getting killed by the child server process and I can't seem to find out how and why or any solutions to this.

My console app creates a new cmd.exe child process that runs a "java -jar server.jar" command when starting the server. When stopping the server a simple "stop" message is written to the standard input of the child process. This all works fine and the java server stops.

However as soon as the child process exits, the console app unexpectedly crashes and the Windows "Program has stopped working." dialog appears. **The curious thing is that I have tested the application on my programming laptop that runs Windows 10 and it runs without any issues there both in release and debug mode. My server machine is running Windows 7 however, so it seems to somehow be a Windows 7 problem.**

Now there's no code I can really show you since it's the java and cmd.exe child process performing the exit and I of course didn't code the server.jar file. But I will attach an image link of the console when it crashes just for fun.

The child process does not have a separate window, it inherits handles from the parent console app and writes to the parent's STDOUT so messages from the child show in the main app's console.

I have tried starting the child process with CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP flag, still crashes.

I have tried ignoring SIGINT and SIGTERM signals, still crashes.

I have also verified that the application doesn't start execution of the commands following the server shutdown call (writing stop message to stdin of server process) so they can't be the problem.

If anyone has any tips or ideas about what could be the issue I'm all ears. Thanks!

[Console application crashes, Windows "Program has stopped working." dialog is not shown on picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87DZ7.png)

EDIT:

Okay, so I created a minimal reproducible example. Here is all the needed code (for C++ main function):

```
//security attributes for pipes
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

//handles for child standard input/output
HANDLE child_stdin_rd = NULL;
HANDLE child_stdin_wr = NULL;

if (!CreatePipe(&child_stdin_rd, &child_stdin_wr, &saAttr, 0))
    return -1;

if (!SetHandleInformation(child_stdin_wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    return -1;

STARTUPINFOW startupInfo;
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
startupInfo.hStdInput = child_stdin_rd;
startupInfo.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
startupInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

//cmd.exe path
wstring exepath = L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";

//cmd command to start server
wstring command = L"cmd.exe /c java -Xms1G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar nogui";
LPWSTR com = new wchar_t[command.size() + 1];
copy(command.begin(), command.end(), com);
com[command.size()] = 0;

if (!CreateProcessW(exepath.c_str(), com, 0, 0, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, 0, 0, &startupInfo, &processInfo))
    return -1;

//sleep for 1 min, letting server start up
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::minutes(1));

//command to stop server
string stopCmd = "stop\n\0";
DWORD stopCmdByteSize = stopCmd.size() * sizeof(char);

if (!WriteFile(child_stdin_wr, stopCmd.c_str(), stopCmdByteSize, 0, 0))
    return -1;

CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
CloseHandle(child_stdin_wr);
```

*To reproduce this*, your machine would need to be **running Windows 7** and in the same folder as the application must be a **Minecraft server.jar file** (version 1.15.2 at time of writing this) which you can get from [their website.](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/) Also, the server might need some setting up first, running it for the first time by double-clicking .jar file creates all needed server files, you must open "eula.txt" and accept the EULA by changing `eula=false` to `eula=true`. Then the server should be good to go.

Like stated before, I didn't code the server.jar file and thus do not know the complete behavior of the java server program.

Comment: Could be Undefined behaviour in the program that manifests differently under Windows 7 than it did under Windows 10 or differently under whatever load your server is under. Crom only knows. I suggest manufacturing a [mre] to reduce the surface area the bug has to hide in. If making the MRE doesn't shake loose the bug, post the MRE here.

Comment: I have included a minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: You may have better luck using RCON, which is a protocol built into the Java edition server used to remotely manage a server with a simple TCP packet format, rather than trying to write commands to the stdin of the program. See https://wiki.vg/RCON for the docs.

Comment: @EricReed Ah yes, that does sound like a very good alternative. Could then even start the server as a detached process (not a child process), which would most definitely rid me of this issue. Great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: No problem. :) (I added my comment as an answer so the question doesn't stay marked as unanswered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug found! Problem solved!**

Ahh, after some vigorous thinking and reading the docs again to verify the code is correct I found the culprit.

In the call to the `WriteFile()` function I forgot to give it a pointer to a DWORD so that it can update the number of bytes the function has written.

So the following code:

```
if (!WriteFile(child_stdin_wr, stopCmd.c_str(), stopCmdByteSize, 0, 0))
    return -1;
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

if (!WriteFile(child_stdin_wr, stopCmd.c_str(), stopCmdByteSize, &bytesWritten, 0))
    return -1;
```

So I guess it was a kind of undefined behavior that Windows 10 could handle but Windows 7 couldn't, resulting in the program crashing.. Kind of feel embarrassed for writing this lengthy post because of a small error in a function call, but there you have it folks! Thanks to those who gave tips! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using RCON, which is a protocol built into the Java edition server used to remotely manage a server with a simple TCP packet format, rather than trying to write commands to the standard input of the server directly.

See [wiki.vg's page on RCON](https://wiki.vg/RCON) for an explanation on the packet format.